# sorl-thumbnail's template tags do nothing

Tags: python, django, sorl-thumbnail

I'm using sorl-thumbnail to get some images to crop.

I have a model looking like this

```
from django.db import models
from sorl.thumbnail import ImageField

class Photo(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="uploads")
```

and inside my template I have

```
{% load thumbnail %}

{% thumbnail photo.image "200x100" as im %}
    <img src="{{ im.url }}">
{% endthumbnail %}
```

This doesn't output anything. If i do `<img src='{{photo.image.url}}'>` the image displays fine within the browser. I also have sorl-thumbnail inside my INSTALLED_APPS and I sync'd the database and have the thumbnail_kvstore table setup.

Can someone help me please. What could cause the images to not be cropped or even displayed?

Comment: Did you have PIL or imagemagick installed? Did you get any error at all?

Comment: You're importing `sorl.thumbnail.ImageField` but using `django.db.models.ImageField`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman http://thumbnail.sorl.net/examples.html#model-examples says that I should import ImageField and it'll work. Is that not the case?

Comment: @dotty ah, Daniel is right, you should be using `ImageField` instead of `models.ImageField` as per documentation says.

Comment: @dotty but those examples import `ImageField` and *use* it. You're importing it and using something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Your code looks fine, so the problem should come from other parts.</strike>

The first thing you can do is to set `THUMBNAIL_DEBUG = True` in your `settings.py` and see why the error occurs.

Are you using `virualenv` and `PIL` for image library? Make sure your `PIL` is compiled and installed with `jpeg` and `png/gif` support which requires `libjpeg` and `zlib`.

Edit: As @DanielRoseman pointed out in the comment, you are actually using `django.db.models.ImageField`, changing

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="uploads")
```

to

```
image = ImageField(upload_to="uploads")
```

to use `sorl.thumbnail.ImageField` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a cleanup, or if that fails, clear. [Documentation](http://thumbnail.sorl.net/management.html#thumbnail-clear)

This resolved the problem for me when I was getting unexpected output. Maybe it will work for you.